# Rails 4 settings params in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I override params in a rails 4 controller?

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
params[:post_type_id] = 2
@post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
```

This throws a `Post type can't be blank` error even though I'm setting it manually.

Here is what my strong parameter function looks like:

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :post_type_id)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `permit`. It's returning a new hash, so you're not actually changing the params variable (which isn't a normal variable anyway)

This can easily be fixed by just going:

```
post_details = post_params
post_details[:post_type_id] = 2
@post = current_user.posts.new(post_details)
```

Comment: how could it be implemented for this problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901150/how-to-set-values-of-nested-parameters-in-rails-4-from-controller-method