# How to set values of nested parameters in Rails 4 from controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have request model and nested model filled_cartridges
when I create new request object i also need to set the values of nested params inside create controller method. I have many nested params so i need to iterate through them, something like that:

```rb
params[:request][:filled_cartridges_attributes].each do |_,value|
  # here i try to set :client_id parameter, which is nested
  # where @client.id is defined
    value[:client_id] = @client.id # i am pretty sure that the problem is here
  # is it a correct way of ding that?

end
```

EDIT:

```html
has_many :filled_cartridges, inverse_of: :request, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :filled_cartridges, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['title'].blank? },allow_destroy: true
```

and my nested model:

```html
   create_table :filled_cartridges do |t|
 t.integer :client_id, null: false
        t.string :cartridge_name, null: false
 t.integer :cartridge_id, null: false
 t.integer :request_id, null: false
 t.integer :count, default: 1
 t.datetime :fill_date
        t.timestamps null: false
    end
```

here client_id,request_id and cartridge_id are all should should be set inside controller. 
And my strong params:

```html
def request_params
  params.require(:request).permit(:name, :address, :phone, :mobile,:date,
 :filled_cartridges_attributes => [:client_id,:cartridge_name,:cartridge_id,
    :request_id,:count,:fill_date,:_destroy,:id],

end
```

Comment: I suggest reading up on [Nested Attributes in ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: @deefour, thats what i am using for doing that.

Comment: Great, however there is no mention of anything having to do with your models in the provided code. Help us help you. Provide the relevant code and detail surrounding the issue you're having. It's completely unclear how you're trying to persist data, what your models look like, what you're trying to do with `value`, etc...

Comment: @deefour i have edited my question a little bit.